# How to mock a method with custom annotation in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a a service which is protected by oAuth. This is the structure for my RestController:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
public class MainController {
@PostMapping("/v1/api")
    @CustomAuthorizer(RequestURI = "api", ResourceType = ResourceType.API, GrantAccess = GrantAccess.EXECUTE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Details>> api(
            @ApiParam(value = "Provide here request body", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody Input input,
            @Valid @RequestParam("tId") String tenantId, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String auth) {
}
```

This is my Test for the same

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MainControllerMockTest {
@WithMockUser( username = "test")
    @Test
    public void testApi() throws Exception {
        Input input = new Input();
        //Set input here
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/api?tId=test")
                .content(inputJson).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJsd2lsbGlhbXMxNiIsInJvbGVzIjoidXNlciIsImlhdCI6MTUxNDQ0OTgzM30.WKMQ_oPPiDcc6sGtMJ1Y9hlrAAc6U3xQLuEHyAnM1FU")
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
        System.out.println(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
        assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }
}
```

Authentication is done by our custom oAuth library, So when /api is called it checks for permissions, is there any way i can bypass that ? I tried mocking that Code as well but it didn't work. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: If you mock that method nothing will be tested, as you have a mock. You have to send valid credentials with the `MockMvc` request, the `@WithMockUser` won't work here as that only works when you don't call an "external" server which you do when using `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: The default configuration of  `@SpringBootTest` still uses a mocked servlet environment and doesn't start the embedded servlet container (unless you choose `RANDOM_PORT`, `DEFINED_PORT`). Can you try to add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to your test class, inject `@Autowired MockMvc;` and try it again? There's an example available in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.with-mock-environment).

Comment: @rieckpil : Actually That CustomAnnotation calls an external API to check for permissions that is very it fails. If i do `@AutoConfigureMockMvc will it configure that?

Comment: I also tried overriding that method which checks for that , It's annotated with @Before still instead of calling my Implemetation it calls the original one.

Comment: Try creating mock of CustomAnnotation(or the respective class) and mock method which trigger external api call.

Comment: @SivaKumar i will try doing that again , as i have already tried.